# what is capablity of component in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell what is capablity of component in android.I know intent filter is capablity of component.can anybody explain what is that?

thanks

Comment: capability of component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Intent object is a bundle of information. It contains information of interest to the component that receives the intent (such as the action to be taken and the data to act on) plus information of interest to the Android system (such as the category of component that should handle the intent and instructions on how to launch a target activity).